# How to provide acces to my Video folder to Guest account

Tags: 14.04

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I would like to give to the guest account read access to the Video/Movies folder that is below to /home/myuser/ directory.

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: That depends partially on the location of the folder in question. Is it on an internal or an external drive? What's the file system? Is it located below your home directory?

Comment: Yep, it is below my internal user home directory. the file system is ext4.

Answer (score 0):

You can allow *everybody* (including guests) to access this folder, if you give *other* users read and execution permissions to

- the folder in question and everything below it (recursively) and
- every folder between `/` and the folder in question.

#### Example:

You want to allow everybody to access `/home/cristiano/Videos/Movies`. Therefore you need to

- allow everybody to access `/home/cristiano/Videos/Movies`, the folder itself, and its content:

  ```
  chmod -R a+rX /home/cristiano/Videos/Movies
  ```
- allow everybody to access to `/`, `/home`, `/home/cristiano`, and `/home/cristiano/Videos`. Conveniently, `/` and `/home` are already accessible to everybody and you only need:

  ```
  chmod a+rX /home/cristiano /home/cristiano/Videos
  ```

All of this can be done through the *Permissions* tab of Nautilus' file property dialogue instead of the command line.

Comment: Hi David. I have a doubt. do I need to allow access to everyone to /home/cristiano and /home/cristiano/Videos in order to allow access to /home/cristiano/Video/Movies ?

Comment: The way I wrote it, other users will only be able to list those directories, but they won't be able to read or write any files in there. Other directories below them remain unreadable. There are ways to only allow traversal of those directories (no content listing), but that would require the guest user to know the exact path to `/home/cristiano/Videos/Movies` (which could be achieved through a well-placed symbolic link).

Comment: I did the first chmod you suggested. but after logged with guest if I try to enter into home folder with nautilus I got a not authorized dialog

Comment: Did you run the 2nd `chmod` command or otherwise allow other users to read and traverse the mentioned folders?

Comment: Yep, I run the 2nd chmod command. And in order to test I've created another user. That new user was able to access the Movies folder but unfortunately the guest account no.

Comment: Please run `ls -ld` on all the locations mentioned in my answer and post the output.